# How to make flutter layout in both column & row as well?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i just started to learn flutter and I have a problem for making layout like this picture below, what code for make layout [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khH1v.png)

Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Container 1'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('Container 2'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Container 3'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From that code that I write, absolutely different from what i expected to be, please help, i'm new on this and want to make one step ahead for my skill to be better. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just convert your `Column` Widget to `Row` and add one center widget inside with `Expand` and add `Column` widget there.

```
        child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 100.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                        ),
                        Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                        )
                    ],
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 100.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                ),
           ],
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: Container(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      height: 100.0,
                      width: 100.0,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: this one works! thanks for helping me, i just realized that I can use Expanded things :)